# Retrieve record specific date and time in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to retrieve the data from an Oracle datetime column from

```
    26/03/2024 11:00:00. AM +00:00
```

to

```
    27/03/2024 03:00:00. AM +00:00
```

as one day record for 26/03/2024 using sysdate.

Can you please help me to write the SQL query in Oracle to search by date and time?

I want get the results what ever sold detail current date 11 am until next date 3 am as one record.

Expected results:

[image: desired output]

Example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some date math. If you subtract 3 hours and 1 second from your TRANSACTION_DATE you will fit the data into same day.

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select  To_Date('26/03/2024 11:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "TRANSACTION_DATE", 2 "QTY", 50 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
          Select  To_Date('27/03/2024 03:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "TRANSACTION_DATE", 2 "QTY", 50 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
          Select  To_Date('27/03/2024 11:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "TRANSACTION_DATE", 2 "QTY", 50 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
          Select  To_Date('28/03/2024 03:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "TRANSACTION_DATE", 2 "QTY", 50 "AMOUNT" From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--    S Q L :
Select   TRUNC(TRANSACTION_DATE + NUMTODSINTERVAL( -3, 'Hour') + NUMTODSINTERVAL( -1, 'Second')) "A_DATE", 
         Sum(QTY) "QTY", Sum(AMOUNT) "AMOUNT"
From     tbl
Group By TRUNC(TRANSACTION_DATE + NUMTODSINTERVAL( -3, 'Hour') + NUMTODSINTERVAL( -1, 'Second'))
Order By TRUNC(TRANSACTION_DATE + NUMTODSINTERVAL( -3, 'Hour') + NUMTODSINTERVAL( -1, 'Second'))
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
A_DATE          QTY     AMOUNT
-------- ---------- ----------
26.03.24          4        100
27.03.24          4        100    */
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I get exactly what i'm looking. Just how can I get it the sales only for current date. I mean where condition how can I  add sysdate -3 HOURS.

Comment: to_char(A_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') =to_char(sysdate - (3 / 24), 'DD/MM/YYYY')  i added like this